# Как открыть картинку капчи с определенного сайта?

Tags: python

Хочу получить данные по запросам с сайта на котором имеется капча. При копировании, url капчи выглядит примерно таким: *data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...mQD0IfsFMIBAGpByAYAQhAWRx0AOhMWRw0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADa5z/ONZDRoyzO/wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==*

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при запросе капчи код показывал мне эту капчу и я вводил ее и продолжал работать. Но при попытке открытия возникает ошибка: *OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw0*
Код примерно таков

```
url = "data:image/jpg;base64,"+response.json()["image"]
image = Image.open(url)
image.show()
token = input()
```

Comment: Так Вы из кэша открываете картинку.  Не с url

Comment: При наведении мыши на картинку в браузере и нажатии кнопки копировать URL картинки, в буфер обмена идет именно такой текст. Прочитал сейчас что это картинка но в формате base64

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему таким образом:

```
import base64
from io import BytesIO #импортируем библиотеки

imgBase64 = response.json()["image"] #здесь получаем картинки из запроса по ключу "image" в base64 либо просто копируем и вставляем код вида (iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS...mQD0IfsFMIBAGpByAYAQhAWRx0AOhMWRw0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADa5z/ONZDRoyzO/wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==), то есть без заголовков "data:image/jpg;base64"
image = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(imgBase64)))#здесь конвертируем в картинку наш код
image.show() #здесь открываем картинку
```